# `tlmgr: Remote repository is newer than local (2017 < 2018)` but I just did a fresh install?

Tags: texlive, updating, tlmgr

First time I saw `tlmgr: Remote repository is newer than local (2017 < 2018)`
I was surprised because my OS is less than a week old, but sometimes the repositories are out of date so did `sudo apt purge texlive`, then went to the [recommended download site](http://ctan.math.illinois.edu/systems/texlive/tlnet/), got `install-tl-unx.tar.gz` and ran through the script. Seems fine, definitely compiles stuff.

Now to try an install a package, I do `sudo tlmgr update --self` and get back 
`tlmgr: Remote repository is newer than local (2017 < 2018)`

So my texlive is 100% definitely 2018, but somehow my tlmgr is still 2017?
(overleaf is looking better and better....) how do I properly diagnose/resolve this?

Comment: Could you please verify that you really ran tlmgr from the fresh installation and not some different tlmgr binary?

Comment: @TeXnician Um, not sure how? `which tlmgr` returns `/usr/bin/tlmgr` and the new install is located in `/usr/local/texlive/2018`.

Comment: Could you do a `file /usr/bin/tlmgr`? Where does it point to?

Comment: @TeXnician oh it goes to  `/usr/bin/tlmgr: symbolic link to ../share/texlive/texmf-dist/scripts/texlive/tlmgr.pl`. That is probably a remnant of a previous install...

Comment: Yes, it is. You should really clean that up and then run `tlmgr path add` with the *new* tlmgr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to follow up the answer was that `sudo apt purge texlive` did not remove the previous tlmgr. Perhaps it was overzealous but I decided to `apt purge` anything related to latex, then manually remove anything still remaining. Then I ran the `install-tl-unx.tar.gz` script and tlmgr is working fine.